# (Another) Correct (?) regex not understood by sed

Tags: regex, sed, zsh, regex-group, regexp-replace

According to https://regex101.com/r/KVQPk0/1, the following regex (in my real use case, I need the group for back references):

```
<latex>\$([^$]*)\$<\/latex>
```

(full) matches the string `<latex>$\rightarrow$</latex>`, but this seems to not be understood by `sed`. Indeed:

```
echo "<latex>$\\\rightarrow$</latex>" | sed -E -e "#<latex>\$([^$]*)\$</latex>#\:math\:\&$1@#d"
```

(which should return an empty string) verbatim returns:

```
<latex>$\rightarrow$</latex>
```

What is the regex that matches `<latex>$\rightarrow$</latex>` from `sed`'s point of view?

### Edit

I mixed up my tests and the command which should return nothing (AFAIU) is:

```
echo "<latex>$\\\rightarrow$</latex>" | sed -E -e "#<latex>\$([^$]*)\$</latex>#d"
```

### Edit 2

My shell is `zsh`.

Comment: If you `echo` strings `"<latex>$\\\rightarrow$</latex>"` and `"#<latex>\$([^$]*)\$</latex>#\:math\:\&$1@#d"` you'll notice neither of them produce the intended result. Work on your ``\``s.

Comment: It's best to put a regexp inside single quotes, not double quotes, so that the backslashes will be treated literally.

Comment: The first error is assuming that regex101 is compatible with `sed`. The second, if I am reading your question correctly, is failing to backslash-escape the first `#` sign.

Comment: Back-references in `sed` are `\1`, `\2`, etc. not `$1`, `$2`.

Comment: You seem to be missing the `s` part of the `s###` command. But then you say "should return an empty string" -- are you intending to match the line and delete it or transform it?

Comment: @Barmar Are you sure? E.g. `echo '<latex>$\rightarrow$</latex>'` returns `ightarrow$</latex>`. But okay, it's simpler with single quotes since only one backslash is needed to escape a backslash, `echo '<latex>$\\rightarrow$</latex>'` returning `<latex>$\rightarrow$</latex>`.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I don't see that. That would happen if you used `$'...'` or `echo -e`, since that interprets C-style escape sequences, so `\r` is a carriage return.

Comment: @tripleee About regex101 compatibility with `sed`, have better pointers? About the `#` signs, they are just `sed` delimiters (I didn't use `/` since such a sign is part of the involved string (`</latex>`). But I realize that I made a mistake in my OP (I'll edit it).

Comment: @Barmar Maybe my shell (`zsh`, configured through [Oh My Zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/)) is configured to make automatically and silently use of the `-e` option of `echo`?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Yes, I assumed bash. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88307/escape-sequences-with-echo-e-in-different-shells

Comment: @DenisBitouzé If this is a problem specifically with `echo`, you can use `printf '%s\n'` instead. EDIT: `printf` is generally recommended for scripts because it's much more predictable. `echo` is known for behaving differently in different shells.

Comment: Note that this only affects `echo`, not the argument to `sed`.

Comment: @glennjackman I'll edit my question, initially confusing (sorry!).

Comment: @Barmar About `printf` generally recommended for scripts, in fact my scripts didn't rely on `echo` (and failed on this regexp, which is why I asked here). I used it here to ask a self contained question. I'll try with `printf`.

Comment: @Barmar Indeed, `printf '%s\n' '<latex>$\rightarrow$</latex>'` returns `<latex>$\rightarrow$</latex>`. BTW, it works the same with double quotes: `printf '%s\n' "<latex>$\rightarrow$</latex>"`.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I don't know zsh's quoting rules, I just use bash. But I know they're different.

Comment: @Barmar (Off topic) I used to use `bash`. Now, I'll never go back to it, `zsh` being much much more powerful. In addition, the transition is very smooth.

Comment: That's fine, but since more programmers know bash than zsh, you need to be your own expert on the differences. And you should tag the questions with your shell, since we'll usually assume bash.

Comment: @Barmar `zsh` now stipulated.

Comment: Regex101 lets you choose a "flavor" from its hamburger menu; there's two variants of PCRE, Python, Go and EcmaScript (JavaScript) but no `sed` or POSIX flavor. You had selected Javascript for your test. Of course, you have to know that there are many different regex flavors for this to appear relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments, here is the regex that matches `<latex>$\rightarrow$</latex>` from `sed`'s point of view:

```
printf '%s\n' '<latex>$\rightarrow$</latex>' | sed -E -e '/<latex>\$([^$]*)\$<\/latex>/d'
```